# Quit and remove application from RAM

Tags: android

I have 6 `activities` in my `application`.

In 2 `activities`, I have coded quit `button`, but whenever I quit my `application` with that button, and start that app from "Recent applications" section, it continues from that activity.
How to code it in such a way that when I restart it from "Recent applications" section, it starts from the very first activity.
This is my code.

```
public void clickexit(View v)
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

In XML file,

```
android:onClick="clickexit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your Android version is 4.1 or higher use this

```
finishAffinity(); 

System.exit(0);  // try this one
```

else you can try this

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(YourActivity.this);
```

For more details refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

Comment: how are you using it can you share

Comment: @DeepChhowala try `System.exit(0);` pls, i have edited the asnswer

Comment: Great, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**Read this document:** [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#clear)

If you put `android:excludeFromRecents` in your manifest will do it. Also you can find more tools with that link.

Comment: It doesn't help me in the last activity. Working only for one activity.